# Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret

Tags: python, root

I've recently installed root on a system running Mac OS X 10.8

In pasting the error on StackOverflow, I've replaced my home folder title with a `xyzzy` to protect my name.

When attempting to `import ROOT` while in a python interactive mode, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xyzzy/Documents/Code/root/lib/ROOT.py", line 103, in <module>
import libPyROOT as _root
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xyzzy/Documents/Code/root/lib/libPyROOT.so, 2):         
Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
  Referenced from: /Users/xyzzy/Documents/Code/root/lib/libMathCore.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/xyzzy/Documents/Code/root/lib/libMathCore.so
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error? ROOT was installed with MacPorts.

Comment: pix, so no-one else makes the same mistake I did in my now-deleted answer (assuming the tilde was a bash homedir shortcut), I've changed your use of `~` to use `xyzzy` instead.

Comment: In examining the declarations of the various `*sincos*` functions in `/usr/include/math.h` on my OS X 10.9 system, they are all marked as `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_NA)`, meaning they wouldn't be available on your 10.8 system.  So my guess would be that the version of root you're using is compiled against OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Adam to the original post describes the issue. I had to upgrade to OS X 10.9 in order to install ROOT, as it was compiled against OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer describes the issue, whoever upgrading to another MacOSX version may not be the only possible solution.

I came across a similar issue with `numpy` and [installing instead an earlier version of the package solved the problem](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12939#issuecomment-511119279):

```sh
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall numpy
python3 -m pip install numpy==1.15 --user
```

As it worked with `numpy`, it might well work with older versions of other packages.